# How to enter terminal buffer using command?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

As title. Assume my cursor is already at the terminal buffer, but it's still in normal mode. I'm trying to use `TermEnter` to enter terminal mode when ever I switch to a terminal buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be ridiculously hard:

### Solution 1: no blink on switch terms, can't change bg-color on `TermEnter`: (simple, so preferred)

```lua
vim.cmd("au BufEnter,TermOpen term://* if &buflisted | set winhl=Normal:CoolBlack | startinsert | endif")
vim.cmd("au BufLeave term://* if &buflisted | set winhl= | stopinsert | endif")
```

### Solution 2: blink on switch terms, can change bg-color on `TermEnter`: (best UX if blink could be fixed)

```lua
  vim.cmd("au TermEnter term://* if &buflisted | set winhl=Normal:CoolBlack | endif")
  vim.cmd('au TermLeave,BufLeave term://* set winhl=')
  vim.cmd("au TermOpen term://* if &buflisted | set winhl=Normal:CoolBlack | startinsert | endif")
  vim.cmd("au BufEnter term://* if &buflisted | startinsert | endif")
  -- vim.cmd("au BufEnter,TermOpen term://* if &buflisted | set winhl=Normal:CoolBlack | startinsert | endif")
  vim.cmd("au BufLeave term://* if &buflisted | set winhl= | stopinsert | endif")

vim.keymap.set({'n', 't'}, '<M-}>', function ()
  vim.cmd('BufferLineCycleNext')
  vim.cmd('normal M')
end, NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
```

Some notes:

- Use the first argument of `keymap.set` to set shortcuts for terminal mode. **Don't detect terminal mode during the execution of the shortcut**.
- There are two situations that you need to reset the color.
- `TermOpen` is needed since `BufEnter` won't be triggered after calling `:term`.